# how to dynamically resize UILabel on UICollectionviewcell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I have a UILabel on a UICollectionview cell that will be populated once the data is downloaded from the server. The uilabel holds a string of variable length.

I have subclassed the UICollectionviewcell and I have programmatically added constraints to center the UILabel as well as fix it at a given Y position. Thus the height of the cell is fixed and the UILabel is position is fixed as well.

Where would I add the code to dynamically change the height of the UILabel? Would it be in the subclassed cell or in the Viewcontroller creating the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the

```
UILabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

and add constraint to pin the UILabel to all the edges of UICollectionViewCell.